# Where is website administrator tools in vs 2013 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Where I can find website administrator tools? I tried to find in 
[image]

There isn't any similar tool.

Comment: There's an answere http://forums.asp.net/p/1940600/5528631.aspx?Re+Where+is+website+administrator+tools+in+vs+2013+RC

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft just removed it for no reason (they are evil)... it`s easier if you just use VS2010 ou VS2012 to configure users and roles with Administration Tool, then go back to VS2013... or you can configure an extension like this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments